# sometimes can't paste data from chrome to EXCEL (but works fine with WORD or any other software!))

Tags: excel, selenium, google-chrome, copy, paste

I use selenium to automatically copy something from Google Chrome and paste it to my excel sheet.

I think the "copy" part is successful because I can paste them to Word or notepad. However, when I paste it to excel sheet, it only pastes stuff I copied previously from other excel sheets (not the current stuff from Chome). There is no error message, I don't know what's going on here.

The weird thing is that sometimes it works, sometimes problematic, it's really driving me nuts. Any thoughts, guys?

Thanks very much!!

Comment: I just found that, IF I HAVEN'T COPIED anything from another EXCEL sheet before I copy from Chome to excel sheet, it works fine. But after I copied something from another excel sheet before I copy from Chome, I can only paste stuff from my first sheet..

Comment: Hello, it would be very helpful if you had the code and libraries you are using. Please show a working version of you code that we can help you fix.

Comment: this might have to do with Excel trying to use an OLE paste and/or copy.  Post your code...